# AdMob not displaying the banner ad on my app why?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

So I tried implementing AdMob to my project but my ad is not showing up and I have no idea why.
I was following a guide online which I can't seem to find at this point but when they did it, it worked just fine, and I followed all the steps, I am starting to consider that it might be Xamarin but I am not sure.

I have a AdMobRenderer.cs that looks like this

```
    using Google.MobileAds;
    using UIKit;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

    namespace AdMobTestProject.iOS
    {
        public class AdMobRenderer : ViewRenderer
        {
//hiding the key for this question
            private const string adMobId = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx/xxxxxxx";
            private BannerView adView;
            private bool viewOnScreen;

            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                if (e.NewElement == null)
                    return;
                if (e.OldElement == null)
                {
                    adView = new BannerView(AdSizeCons.SmartBannerPortrait)
                    {
                        AdUnitID = adMobId,
                        RootViewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController
                    };

                    adView.AdReceived += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        if (!viewOnScreen)
                        {
                            this.AddSubview(adView);
                        }

                        viewOnScreen = true;
                    };
                    Request request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
                    adView.LoadRequest(request);
                    base.SetNativeControl(adView);
                }
            }

            public AdMobRenderer()
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

And then the XAML aswell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdMobTestProject"
             x:Class="AdMobTestProject.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <local:AdMobView WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="50"></local:AdMobView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And ofcourse the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace AdMobTestProject
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class AdMobView : ContentView
    {
        public AdMobView()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Why is it not displaying anything when I deploy the app to my device? iPhone 7.
I am using Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Do have any exceptions? In your I have a AdMobRenderer, have you checked for any null pointer?

Comment: No exceptions and yes, no issues there.

Comment: are you able to view test ads? Capture logs and update in your question ( logs need not be exception but response from admob ). Also check ad blocking settings on phone

Comment: @AmodGokhale I tried using test ads and nothing, admob logs are empty and I do not have any ablock on my phone.

Comment: there should be something in logs for reason of not showing advertisements. Can you try to add different ad id. Make sure you are adding ad Id and not app id ( most common mistake )

Comment: also try posing ad to different position instead of OnElementChanged which can hash out any specific issue with OnElementChanged

Comment: @AmodGokhale Can you send me some test ads?

Answer (score 0):

Check the space available for the adview should not be less than 360 pixel wide so check the main layout of the page if there margins remove them.
as a clue check the build output window in visual studio it will show if the ads are loaded or not and show a reason for why ads are not visible if they are loaded.
in your sample remove the WidthRequest.

this is a late reply for future searches.

Answer (score 0):

Try change adMobId to a test ad id.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

(ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111)

I had the same issue, and if I navigated to another page and went back my ads showed up.

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)